# Gtk menu with icons

Tags: gtk

This is critical part of my run-time created menu:

```
GtkWidget *menu, *menu_item;
menu = gtk_menu_new();

menu_item = gtk_image_menu_item_new_with_label("Uredi...");

//approach1 - icon don't work
//gtk_image_menu_item_set_image(GTK_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM(menu_item), gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_EDIT, GTK_ICON_SIZE_MENU));

//approach2 - icon also don't work
gtk_image_menu_item_set_image(GTK_IMAGE_MENU_ITEM(menu_item), GTK_WIDGET(gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_EDIT, GTK_ICON_SIZE_MENU)));

gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menu_item);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(menu_item), "button-release-event", G_CALLBACK(menu_RELEASE), (gpointer)"");

gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(GTK_MENU(menu), button, NULL);
gtk_widget_show_all(menu);
```

Menu works OK but this is only one "imagemenuitem" on which I see label but don't see image.
What can be wrong here?

Gtk2, Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe icons in menus and buttons are no longer enabled by default.  You need to turn them on to make them show up.

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons true
```

Or using `dconf`:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/menus-have-icons true
```

Comment: Thanx Sean. It seem's you're right. However, suggested solution don't work for me. I try also with gconf-editor with no results.

Comment: This setting is now controlled by dconf, since the Gnome desktop has transitioned away from gconf. I can't remember the name of the setting and can't check it at the moment, but it should be under `org.gnome.desktop` somewhere.

Comment: Thanx tomato. I find it with dconf-editor under org.gnome.desktop.interface. There I checked "buttons-have-icons" and "menus-have-icons", but still haven't image on menu.

Comment: I still can't fond how to get this but I'm wondering if image will be showed if is possible to use "custom icon" instead of stock icon?

Comment: Seems this doesn't work anymore with current Gnome 3.10.

Answer (score 4):

Hey pretty old question so probably not much use. But I was having a very similar problem with a menu not showing images (in my case it was popup menu triggered by a button).

The way I solved it was calling the

```
gtk_image_menu_item_set_always_show_image(menu_item,TRUE);
```

This solved my problem, now my images always show :D woot :) As passing in 1 (true) means it will always show.

Ref:
http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkImageMenuItem.html

Comment: Don't use `1`, that's a [`gboolean`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Basic-Types.html#gboolean)-type argument, so use [`TRUE`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Standard-Macros.html#TRUE:CAPS).